# Save contact data to mobile phone from website like QR Contact

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ios

Is there a way to generate a clickable link in html to save some contact information to the users mobile phone?

When I scan a QR-Code, I get the contact information. How can I do this in html/php/JavaScript?

Since android doesn't support vcf files, there should be another way to do this.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/enesser/vCards-JS

Comment: android does support vcf files!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript running on device regular browser can't just write directly to android internal databases or files(unless you have an application installed on the target android device which resolves some certain uri scheme leading to them).

you can use [tel: uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) or direct the user to a ".vcf" file(android Does support it) and have the user decide.